# Calculating Tx Power Level in CoreBluetooth iOS

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

The page on [this url](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.tx_power_level.xml) shows that

The value of the characteristic is a signed 8 bit integer that has a fixed point exponent of 0.

Showing the Examples:
The value 0x12 is interpreted as +18dBm
The value 0xED is interpreted as -18dBm

How to calculate 0xED and get result as -18dBm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This required simple conversion of hexadecimal to decimal values.

0xED-255=237-255=-18

0x12=18

There is nothing more to it.

Comment: From anything beyond 20, you need to subtract 255. If you want to get -1 as a result you need to use 0xFE. That way, you can still obtain all values between -100 and +20.

Comment: To get -100, you use 0x9B etc.

Comment: 0x125 is outside the domain. 0x15=21, 21>20, therefore you need to subtract 255: 21-255=-234, but -234<-100 and therefore is invalid. Do you get this value somehow and are you sure that 0x15 is correct?